# Will adding a half-bath impact the water pressure in the existing bathrooms?

Tags: bathroom

It’s ranch w/full basement. Adding 1/2 bath, so a toilet/sink. Doing it all myself and going smoothly. Above the bathroom are the baths on the main floor which has 1/2 copper. Is the water pressure impact anything to be concerned with? I imagine pressure loss will be noticed if the bath on the main floor is being used at the same time the new basement bath is. Is there any particular/better area to tap into? Thank you

Comment: It really depends on your household pressure and common usage. What's the incoming pressure? Have you had weak pressure issues?

Comment: "if the bath on the main floor is being used at the same time the new basement bath is"; you state that the new equipment is toilet/sink. Standard toilets and bathtubs are not much affected by pressure changes (just fill time). So is your concern specifically about some showering upstairs being affected by a toilet flush and/or sink use downstairs?

Answer (score 1):

The pressure will be the same as you have now, if you notice a change when somebody flushes or used a sink that same effect will be there. Stay with the 1/2” pipe and you should be fine, most fixtures have flow restrictions built into them so a 1/2” line will be sufficient. Depending on where you tap the lines, the pressure drop could be more noticeable. For example if tapped close to the water heater then run to the new 1/2 bath would have the least effect compared to tapping the line for the existing bath 50’ away because of the total volume and length of pipe, but the effect of using 2 faucets at the same time depends on the flow. A bathtub usually has the highest flow where toilets, showers and sinks have relatively low flow rates.